# Local Network not working on one server while the other one works fine

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

So I have two servers (davros - working, kraken - not working) on the same subnet (10.10.28.0/24). They both have the same configurations and yet only one of them works. (Also, I should note that they're both VMS on the same KVM instance running Ubuntu 14.04.

To start, here are each of their /etc/network/interfaces files:

```
# Davros (Working one)

# Interface eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address <davros_ip_addr>
    netmask 255.255.255.192
    network 192.41.71.192
    broadcast 192.41.71.255
    gateway 192.41.71.193

# Interface eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.10.28.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 10.10.0.0
    broadcast 10.10.255.255
```

and

```
# Kraken (Broken one)

# Interface eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address <kraken_ip_addr>
    netmask 255.255.255.192
    network 192.41.71.192
    broadcast 192.41.71.255
    gateway 192.41.71.193

# Interface eth1
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.10.28.2
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 10.10.0.0
    broadcast 10.10.255.255
```

If you were to diff them, the only thing that's different is their ip addresses.

Next, here's the output of ip addr on both:

```
# Davros (Working one)

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:87:86:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet <davros_ip_addr>/26 brd 192.41.71.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe87:8632/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:13:9d:ad brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.28.1/16 brd 10.10.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe13:9dad/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and

```
# Kraken (Broken one)

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:19:c0:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet <kraken_ip_addr>/26 brd 192.41.71.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe19:c0ae/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:eb:ef:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.28.2/16 brd 10.10.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feeb:ef92/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Once again, a diff would only show differences in the actual ip addresses.

Here's my `route -n` output (which is the same on both):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.41.71.193   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
192.41.71.192   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Another thing to clarify, the external network works perfectly fine on both of them. I can ping 8.8.8.8 with no problems. It's just when I try to ping on the local network that kraken (the broken one) fails where davros doesn't.

I've looked all over the place for how to best diagnose this and finally decided I had to ask here. I've been working on this for hours on end. If you need any more information at all, or if you want me to run a command and post the output, please do not hesitate to ask at all. Or clarification. I have no idea what could be causing this. Thank you in advance for any help you give.

Comment: If you hadn't removed the real ip-address from `address <ip_addr>` you should get the error.

Comment: Those are just placeholders for the actual ip addresses. Their real addresses do come out and they are valid and different and not in use anywhere else. Plus, those are the public ip addresses which are not having any problems at all.

Comment: To me everything looks good inside the guests . . . so maybe focus on the networking on the host. (i.e. how the guest networking is configured for KVM)

Comment: I actually ended up just deleting the old guest and cloning davros and then changing the hostname and networking stuff and it all works now. Because I needed this to work. The host on the other hand I know works fine too as I have a few other guests on there with both external and internal ip addresses that are both accessible.

Comment: Would have been interesting to see the actual errors, ie. which IP address you tried to ping and how it failed (ARP resolution, network unreachable, timeout ...) But I guess it's too late to ask that now if you already tore it down. It might be a good idea to drop the question now that it cannot be answered anymore.

Comment: It was always a network or host unreachable. And I tried pinging 10.10.28.1 (which is davros) and a couple others on the local network (10.10.x.x)